# Can't find symbol from another public class

Tags: java, cannot-find-symbol

So I'm making a Binary to Decimal converter and I'm supposed to catch the invalid character if the user inputs an illegal argument. Like if the user inputs 1501 in the Binary field then my program will need to catch the first illegal argument and then output it back to the user to show them their mistake.

My problem is I can't get my illegal_char variable from my isBinary class to come into my parseBinary class.

```
public class Assignment2_gui extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
public int parseBinary(String binary) throws NumberFormatException {
    if (!isBinary(binary)) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid Format for a Binary String - Illegal character: " + illegal_char);
    }
    int power = 0;
    int decimal = 0;
    for (int i = binary.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        if (binary.charAt(i) == '1') {
            decimal += Math.pow(2, power);
        }
        power++;
    }
    return decimal;
}


public boolean isBinary(String binary) {
    int illegal_char;
    for (char ch : binary.toCharArray()) {
        if (ch != '1' && ch != '0'){
            illegal_char = ch;
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

I've tried using static/nonstatic classes and it doesn't seem to matter. I've also tried using:

```
throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid Format for a Binary String - Illegal character: " + isBinary(illegal_char));
```

But I still can't figure it out for sure. I suspect that my isBinary is a boolean class so it can never return an int at all? Would that mean that I would need to make a seperate class to catch the illegal char?

Answer (score 0):

What you said is correct. Your method only returns booleans, so if you wanted to return the char that is invalid, you would have to make a completely different method to return the invalid char, or edit your current one so it returns chars, or whatever you want to get it to return what you want it to.

Comment: I'm trying to do this now but I can't grasp how I'm supposed to contruct the char class to scan through the binary string. I'm using `for (char ch : binary.toCharArray())` for the isBinary method, I know it doesnt work for a char method but that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: I'd say us the String charAt method and a for loop to scan each char and get it individually.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this and can't get it right. Google isn't helping either, sorry I'm just picking this back up after a long break.

Comment: Still stuck on this.

Comment: I took what I learned from here and I believe I have the correct method now. But a new problem has arisen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903170/java-netbeans-8-2-method-cant-find-value-from-another-method