# JAVA: Method can't find value from another method

Tags: java, methods, parameters

So I'm making a Binary to Decimal converter and I'm supposed to catch the invalid character if the user inputs an illegal argument. I believe I have the correct method for catching any characters that aren't 0 or 1.
However, when I try to implement this method into my primary method parseBinary, it says that it "Cannot Find Symbol" for illegal(iChar).

**I can't add any more parameters to parseBinary** because the user is only supposed to enter one string of 0's and 1's. I'm curious if I made this method for nothing because of this restriction, but this is the only way I know of going about it. I'm a novice. Any/all help is very appreciated.

```
public static int parseBinary(String binary) throws NumberFormatException {
    if (!isBinary(binary)) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid Format for a Binary String - Illegal character: " + illegal(iChar));
    }
    int power = 0;
    int decimal = 0;
    for (int i = binary.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        if (binary.charAt(i) == '1') {
            decimal += Math.pow(2, power);
        }
        power++;
    }
    return decimal;
}


public static boolean isBinary(String binary) {
    for (char ch : binary.toCharArray()) {
        if (ch != '1' && ch != '0'){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static char illegal(String iChar)
{
    char test = 0;
    char arr[] = iChar.toCharArray();
    for(char cha : arr)
    {
        if (cha != '1' && cha != '0')
        {
            test = cha;
        }
    }
    return test;
}
```

Comment: You should pass `binary` to it, not `iChar`

Comment: Such a simple solution. Thank you for pointing it out to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mureinik said
instead of doing

```
throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid Format for a Binary String - Illegal character: " + illegal(iChar));
```

you must pass binary to the method illegal

change it to

```
throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid Format for a Binary String - Illegal character: " + illegal(binary));
```